# .htaccess urlrewrite remove number

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to write a regular expression to remove a large number from the end of the URL.

Here are some examples:

```
/uk/futsal-cosmos-10-panel-match-football-white-purple-24100787502654/
/uk/escape-t400-individual-rubber-dumbbells-up-to-50kg-2289101502719397/
/uk/golds-gym-standard-hammertone-plate-25-4mm-1-25kg-x-12-1736702088365877/
```

So basically I need the final numbers removed including the dash.

In the third example, this should become:

```
/uk/golds-gym-standard-hammertone-plate-25-4mm-1-25kg-x-12/
```

i.e. the 12 should remain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If last number always has been preceded by -, try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on

   RewriteRule ^(.*)-[0-9]+/$ /$1/ [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Replace [L,QSA] by [R=301,L] if you want a 301 redirection

For 10 digits after the dash

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-[0-9]{10}/$ /$1/ [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hi thanks - that's a great answer but:
/uk/golds-gym-standard-hammertone-plate-25-4mm-1-25kg-x-12-1736702088365877/

The new URL for that is going to be /uk/golds-gym-standard-hammertone-plate-25-4mm-1-25kg-x-12/ which by your rewrite url would be changed /uk/golds-gym-standard-hammertone-plate-25-4mm-1-25kg-x/ which causes a 404

Comment: Is it possible to make the rewrite rule only match numbers that have more than 10 digits after the dash?

Comment: I just edit for 10 digits after the dash form. Please, test the first form, only last dash will be removed for any last number

Comment: I tested the first form - it removes the last number here: uk/golds-gym-standard-hammertone-plate-25-4mm-1-25kg-x-12/ which should actually remain as it's part of the product description.

Comment: Your edit would mean EXACTLY 10 digits right? I need 10 digits or more to be removed - would this do it?

RewriteRule ^(.*)-[0-9]{9}[0-9]+/$ /$1/ [L,QSA]

Comment: I'm testing that and it seems to work but would appreciate confirmation.

Comment: For 10 or more: RewriteRule ^(.*)-[0-9]{10,}/$ /$1/ [L,QSA]